# Converting Json file to a human readable format?

Tags: json

I have a js file which is in json format and i want to convert this file to a  human readable format.Is there any external software which does that or i have to code it??Am new to this stuff.

Comment: Please do proper tagging for making question more clear

Comment: a json file is basically a text file, it is not a binary format , what are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

Json is a format which looks like plain text. I guess you know what you are asking. If you need to convert a file containing Json text to a readable format, you need to convert that to an Object and implement toString() method(assuming converting to Java object) to print or write to another file in a much readabe format. You can use any Json API for this, for example Jackson JSON API.

```
ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
T t=obj.readValue(File src, Class<T> valueType) 

t.toString();  //this must have been implemented
```

Comment: i want to convert it into a human readable format.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by human readable format? It'll make life easier if you can provide your json file content and "human readable" output.

Comment: Input:           {"windows":[{"tabs":[{"entries":[{"url":"http://websearch.soft-quick.info/","title":"Search","ID":0,"docshellID":9,"docIdentifier":0,"children":[{"url":"http://ad.xtendmedia.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=4017703&pub_url=websearch.soft-quick.info","ID":2

Comment: Output : Tab : 1,window: 1, url : websearch.soft-quick.info/

Comment: You can certainly achieve this like I said using Java. Alternatively, you can do in Javascript but you have to write some script for that.